# TikZ: How do I occasionally suppress the join option?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm drawing some diagrams where most of the nodes are joined to each other, but occasionally I want a break.

Here's how I *thought* I could do it (sorry its so big):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    start chain=going below,
    every node/.style={%
        join,
        on grid,
        on chain,
        draw,
        align=center,
    },
    every join/.style={->,draw}
]

\tikzset{
  none/.style={draw=none},
}

\node (a0) {A0};
\node {B0};

\node [join=by none,right=of a0] (a1) {A1};
\node {B1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the output, `join=by none` has no effect on the unwanted join from B0 to A1:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this, either as a specific option (eg `no join`) or as a style option? I've searched the *pgfmanual.pdf* but found nothing.

Comment: Not sure if this would work in all cases but maybe `\makeatletter\tikzset{no join/.code={\let\tikz@after@path=\pgfutil@empty}}` might give a useable `no join` key.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Hmm, I hadn't really considered open heart surgery on TikZ, but it's an idea!!! It works like a charm; if you'd care to make it an answer, it's the leading accept candidate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `join` option doesn't just set some option that can be changed, it appends a command using `append after command`.  Thus, setting `join` twice leads to multiple joins.  This is how you can join multiple nodes (e.g., `\node [join=with node 1, join=with node 2] {...}`).  So what you really need to do is delete all the `append after command` commands.

Now you probably don't actually want to do that, as it could cause collateral damage.  (Who knows what other options that you're relying on also make use of `append after command` internally?)  Nonetheless, I believe in directly answering people's questions even when I don't think they should use that answer.  So here you go, with a minimal working example that suppresses the join option on one of the nodes:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset after command/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,
    every node/.style={fill=blue!10, draw=blue!20, on chain, join=by ->},
    node distance=1em,
  ]
\node {here};
\node {are};
\node[reset after command] {some};
\node {nodes};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** What if the background is not white? asked by egreg

So I mimic a scenario with a background to verify the logic.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=0.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    start chain=going below,
    every node/.style={%
        join,
        on grid,
        on chain,
        draw,
        align=center,
    },
    every join/.style={->,draw}
]

\tikzset{
  none/.style={->,cyan,line width=5pt}, % remove line width see the artifact
  }

\node (a0) {A0};
\node {B0};

\begin{scope}[every join/.style={->, shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt}]
\node [join=by none,right=of a0] (a1) {A1};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
\draw[fill=cyan] (-0.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,0.5);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}

\node {B1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a possible solution to `reverse the default` mentioned in the comment by the OP. The logic behind the solution is to use a `scope` environment to reverse the default by drawing a shorter connection line, then draw a thick line with `white` color to erase the short line. The erase action is defined by the `none` macro.

```
\begin{scope}[every join/.style={->, shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt}]
 <node commands>
\end{scope}

 none/.style={->,white,line width=5pt},     % remove line width see the artifact
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=0.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    start chain=going below,
    every node/.style={%
        join,
        on grid,
        on chain,
        draw,
        align=center,
    },
    every join/.style={->,draw}
]

\tikzset{
  none/.style={->,white,line width=5pt},     % remove line width see the artifact
  }

\node (a0) {A0};
\node {B0};

\begin{scope}[every join/.style={->, shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt}]
\node [join=by none,right=of a0] (a1) {A1};
\end{scope}

\node {B1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if the background is not white?

Comment: Good thinking, but based on the given data, I assume white. Well. the logic still applies to different color, is it not? Some improvisation may require thou.

Comment: Is the active background color available in some way?

Comment: After 28 mins, I seem to understand your questions --- if I apply  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} ... \end{pgfonlayer}, I think that is what you try to address. Is that the focal point of your 2nd question?

Comment: It seems so. Maybe an experiment with differently colored background can solve any doubt.

Comment: Yes, I just did and posted my update. I like to say thank you very much for tutoring me. Fingers touching my forehead.

Comment: (+1) for dealing with the background colour. But this will still come out wrong if there is something 'in the way' which is drawn before the join, won't it?

Comment: In short, my logic would say to delay/redraw the "something in the way". Or use the first solution given by Harish. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It's an ingenious option, but unfortunately doesn't fulfil my original aim, only hinted at in the question: uncluttered source code.

Answer (score 2):

One way will be to use white color (or similar):

```
\node [join= by {white,->},right=of a0] (a1) {A1};
```

Equivalently using your approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    start chain=going below,
    every node/.style={%
        join,
        on grid,
        on chain,
        draw,
        align=center,
    },
    every join/.style={->,draw}
]

\tikzset{
  none/.style={draw=white},
}

\node (a0) {A0};
\node {B0};

\node [join= by {none},right=of a0] (a1) {A1};
\node {B1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

Sigh, the artefacts remain.

Or use the `join` option on individual nodes like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    start chain=going below,
    every node/.style={%
        %join,
        on grid,
        on chain,
        draw,
        align=center,
    },
    mynode/.style={%
    join
    },
    every join/.style={->,draw}
]

\node[mynode] (a0) {A0};
\node[mynode] {B0};

\node [right=of a0] (a1) {A1};    %% no join here
\node[mynode] {B1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of defining `mynode`, we could have added just `join` in every node except those which needn't be joined.

Comment: Thank you for trying. `draw=white` is a bit intrusive if 'something gets in the way'. And, I could, as you say, add join to every node, but as joins are in the majority, I'd like to find a way to 'reverse the default', to minimise the amount of options, mainly for readability and mantainability.