# Label 1st and last element and code for Enqueue and Dequeue

Tags: labels, nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\tikzset{
    queue element/.style={
        draw,very thin,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.1cm,
        fill=brown!30, 
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize
    },
    >={[scale=0.8]Triangle}
}

\newcommand\x{1}
\newcommand\y{5}
%Enqueue:
\newcommand\m{1}
\newcommand\n{6}
%Dequeue:
\newcommand\s{2}
\newcommand\f{6}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\scope[yshift=-1cm] 
\foreach \i/\name in {\x,...,\y}{
        \node[queue element] (\i) at (1*\i,0){\i};
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\x.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
     }  
   \draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\y.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\endscope

%Enqueue:
\scope[yshift=-3cm] 
\foreach \i in {\m,...,\n}{
        \node[queue element] (\i) at (1*\i,0){\i};
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\m.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
        }  
   \draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\n.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
    \path (-2.5,0) node[right] {Enqueue:};
\endscope

%Dequeue:
\scope[yshift=-5cm] 
\foreach \i in {\s,...,\f}{
        \node[queue element] (\i) at (1*\i,0){\i};
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\s.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
        }  
      \draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\f.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
      \path (-2.5,0) node[right] {Dequeue:};
\endscope

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**If anyone needs this(circled red) just put draw outside of foreach for last elemen and 1st in foreach(like i did in my code):**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Could you please clarify your question by explaining what exactly you want? Your question title doesn't completely explain what it is you're struggling with (at least I don't fully understand what you're asking us). Additionally, please note that you can highlight your code as such by putting three backticks in the lines above and below it (which I've already done for you).

Comment: Unrelated, but `\the\numexpr` does nothing useful where you use it; it would do if you need to do arithmetic with `\x` and friends.

Comment: This is a combination of [this concept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669372) and testing for `\i=\s` and `\i=\f`. You could also give your nodes proper names, say `(i\i)`, and then you can reference them with `(i\s)` and `(i\f)`. The `chains` library could make this even easier by providing `(chain-begin)` and `(chain-end)` names for the first and last node in a chain. And the `pin` option might make it even easier to add an edge to a node.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

You only need to addnodes above last element in your queue:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
 queue element/.style={
        draw, very thin,
        minimum width=1cm ,minimum height=1em,
        fill=brown!30,
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize
        },
    >={[scale=0.8]Triangle}
        }
\newcommand\x{1}
\newcommand\y{5}

\newcommand\m{1}
\newcommand\n{6}

\newcommand\s{2}
\newcommand\f{6}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {\x,...,\y}{
\node[queue element] (\i) at (\i,0) {\i};
     }
\draw[<-] ([yshift=5mm]\x.north) -- ++ (0,5mm) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=5mm]\y.north) -- ++ (0,5mm) node[above] {tail};

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\foreach \i in {\m,...,\n}{
\node[queue element] (\i) at (\i,0) {\i};
        }
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\m.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\n.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {tail};
\node[right] at (-22mm,0) {Enqueue:};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
\foreach \i in {\s,...,\f}{
\node[queue element] (\i) at (1*\i,0){\i};
        }
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\s.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]\f.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {tail};
\node[right] at (-22mm,0) {Dequeue:};
\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: please be consistent in use of LaTeX!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

I'd do this with a `\pic` for the 'queues'. Like this example, trying to replicate (approximately) Zarko's picture:

**Edit**: I changed the use of a global variable because it could cause some conflicts in a complete document (a not `standalone` one). See Egreg's comment.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/queue/.style 2 args={% #1 = first element, #2 = last element
    code={%
      \foreach[count=\j]\i in {#1,...,#2}
      {%
        \draw[pic actions] (\j,-0.25) rectangle ++ (1,0.5);
        \node at (\j+0.5,0) {$\i$};
      }
      \draw[latex-]    (1.5,0.5) --++ (0,1) node[above] {front};
      \draw[latex-] (#2+0.5,0.5) --++ (0,1) node[above] {rear};
  }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % \pics
  \pic[fill=orange!30] at (1,0) {queue={1}{5}};
  \pic[fill=orange!30] at (0,3) {queue={1}{6}};
  \pic[fill=orange!30] at (0,7) {queue={1}{5}};
  % labels
  \node[right] at (-1,3) {\strut Enqueue:};
  \node[right] at (-1,0) {\strut Dequeue:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a standalone document, `\global\let\last\j` might be good, but in a real document it would be risky, possibly disastrous if `\last` is already defined.

Comment: @egreg, what would be a more robust way to do it? And thanks for pointing it, BTW

Comment: Well, the user does know what are the first and the last elements, because they're encoded in `\x` and `\y` (or similarly for the other blocks). No need to “remember” values, they're already given.

Comment: Thanks again, @egreg. It's corrected now!